# Change color of an element based on the text in it

Tags: javascript

Comment: I have a dynamic list of products with status. the code just acts on the first one and for the other it does not make the In Stock color red?

```
<body>
<div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">In Stock</div>
<div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">Available</div>
<div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">In Stock</div>
<div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">In Stock</div>

</body>

<script>

let element = document.getElementById('greenStock');
var textColor = element.innerHTML;



if (textColor === 'In Stock'){
    element.style.color = "red";
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `textColor` is a string, not an element. It doesn’t have a `style` property; `document.getElementById('greenStock')` does.

Answer (score 1):

`textColor` is the `innerHTML` of the element and the property `style` only exists on the element not on the `innerHTML` of the element.

This should work

```html
<html>
    
    <body>
    <div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">In Stock</div>
    <div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">Available</div>
    <div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">In Stock</div>
    <div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">In Stock</div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
    
    let element = document.getElementById('greenStock');
    var textColor = element.innerHTML;
    
    
    
    if (textColor === 'In Stock'){
     element.style.color = "red";
    }
    
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textColor = document.getElementById('greenStock').innerHTML;

//alert(textColor);

if (textColor == 'In Stock'){

    document.getElementById('greenStock').style.color = "#048f00";
} else {
    document.getElementById('greenStock').style.color = "any other color"
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<div id="greenStock" class="zcd-status">In Stock</div>
</body>
</html>
```